# How can I work around applying a modifier to a shape with its shape keys?

Tags: shape-keys

Blender says: I can't apply a modifier while it has shape keys.
If I don't apply the modifier It doesn't allow an FBX export of its shape keys.

So I have to delete all the shape keys apply the modifier then build back the shape keys.

The only way I know how to do this is making a duplicate of the shape with the keys intact and sliding each key one at a time to a value of 1 then select the shapes to then select Join as Shape. It's a long tedious procedure especially if you have a large number of shapes keys.

Is there a better way than how I am doing this?